# Social Auth - Android status update returns 403

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, socialauth

I have implemented [SocialAuth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) in my Android application. Posting a tweet to Twitter works fine.

Updating my status to Facebook using my developer account works fine, how ever with any other account a 403 – Forbidden error is being returned.

Do I need to apply for the “publish_actions” permission in the developer console? – which in turn requires me to submit my apk etc.

Comment: I have changed the App Center Permissions in App Details > Configure App Center Permissions. This does not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** - applications need to be reviewed

Taken from [Facebook's changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

> **We will review how apps use Facebook Login**: Apps requesting more than public_profile, email and the user_friends permission must be reviewed by Facebook before those permissions can be requested from people. Active apps created before April 30th, 2014 have one year before they are required to go through login review, including updates to existing apps. **Facebook apps created after April 30th, 2014 must go through review.**